# how to use "where" in the List<int> like c# in android

Tags: android, list, where-clause

I need to select multiple items. I need the numbers greater than 50.
I do not know how to write this code. Sample C # code defines me what I need.Is this supported in Android?

```
    List<int> _numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
_numbers.add(111);
_numbers.add(54);
_numbers.add(25);
_numbers.add(552);
_numbers.add(58);

// like c# code : _numbers.where(d=>d>=50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate though your list and put the values greater than 50 into another list. You can get the integers greater than 50 with an if-clausel:

> ```
> List<int> xxxx = new ArrayList<Integer>
> for(int value : _numbers){
>     if(value > 50)
>        xxxx.add(value )
> }
> ```